# What is the best way to attach existing database to sql localdb?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

**Context**

I'm working on a desktop app which must be able to run in case of connection loss with the distant sql server : a SQL Server **Express** (I know...) 2012. I'm working on Visual Studio **Express** 2013. So I figured out that my best option is to use SQLLocalDB as my client local DB as I just have to import my data-free mdf file and handle the data synch (which represent a quite simple enough ruleset) by myself. To attach the mdf file to SQLLocalDB, I have two options but I do not understand clearly the consequences of each one.

**Solution 1 - Transact SQL**

[image]

**Solution 2 - Connexion string**

```
"Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName= myDbFile.mdf;"
```

What is the best way to go knowing that I use Entity Framework to access the data in code ?

Comment: Just in case someone else wonders... for solution 1, i had to finish the command with "GO"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is solution #2 is better because it's based on connection string to databse.

In SQL Express you can specify a db name in T-SQL too (`USE DB_NAME`). But people usually specify db in a connection string rather than T-SQL